# Assign keyboard shortcut to "Edit a watch.." shortcut in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I used to be able to Edit my watches by pressing a keyboard shortcut. Now I have to Right click on the watch variable and Select "Edit..." from the popup (which is not very convenient).

There does appear a "Edit..." in the Keymap (see below) but it appears to do nothing. I've tried many key combinations but pressing the keys won't do anything.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/j4Eu5gO.png]

Even in the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-editing-and-removing-watches.html) there is no mention of keyboard shortcut.

**Is there any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to "Edit watch" or is it not supported?**

Comment: Use "Search by shortcut" functionality in `Settings | Keymap` (a button next to search field). On my Keymap (based on "Default") pressing `F2` allows me to edit the debugger watch. **P.S.** From what I see it must be `Other | Set Value...` action that is responsible for this: https://postimg.cc/p98xsDKJ

Comment: Yes that's it! It was "Set value.." You're absolutely correct. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **"Search by shortcut"** functionality in `Settings | Keymap` (a button next to search field). On my Keymap (based on "Default") pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> allows me to edit the debugger watch.

From what I see it must be `Other | Set Value...` action that is responsible for this:

[image]